# Should I reject edits with disturbingly incorrect and/or confusing edit comment? (summary)

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, edit-summary

Sometimes I get an edit to review that has comment which has nothing to do with the edit. Such as a retag edit commented as *fixed grammar* or *improved formatting*. These comments confuse me a lot and make me think the user did something else then he intended to do or thought he was doing. Yet I would accept the edit without hesitation if it wasn't for the comment.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this question is not about spelling. The answers to linked question do not address this issue either. You were the only person to cast close vote and confident about yourself, you made a mistake. Please justify your position.

Comment: It's the same thing. Bad spelling/grammar is the same as "incorrect and confusing". The answer for both will be the same, in my opinion, so my vote stands. Now with your reopen vote this will reach the Reopen queue, so four other users can still reopen it. (Or one other with gold hammer)

Comment: 5 people please reopen this question! It's not a dupe!